# How to get enterprise library configuration and project settings designer reference the same value in app.config

Tags: .net, configuration, app-config, enterprise-library, settings.settings

I would like to configure application and user settings using the design time tools in Visual Studio (2010)

For example:

[image: Settings designer in Visual Studio 2010]

For the application settings I would like to use the Enterprise Library Configuration tools to manage the values and apply environment specific overrides. However the Settings designer uses `<applicationSettings/>` and the entlib framework uses standard `<appSettings>` illustrated in the screenshot below:

[image: App config showing both settings designer and entlib configuration]
How can I get entlib to use the same elements as the settings designer?

I would like to use the auto-generated code that the settings designer generates.

Answer (score 0):

Would be nice if they used the same element. I too would like a better central tool.
Indeed a single config editor tool would be great.
Plugins for each Tag and library it supported.
The ultimate VSIX...
Please MS ...